# Call function in VB.Net DLL without registering the DLL

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic, dllregistration

Is it possible to call a function in a VB.Net dll without having registered the dll file? I need to call it from ASP Classic on shared hosting web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to call a VB.NET DLL from Classic ASP is to make it a COM object and call it as such.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little too green to understand what you mean by "make it a COM object". Is this something to do with how it is programmed or how it is installed? Will it have to be registered on the server?

Comment: Yeah, there used to be a way to make classic WIN32 DLLs from Visual Basic 6 (it was convoluted).  Alas, I don't think it's possible from VB.NET.

Comment: If you build a COM object in VB.NET can you still use the .Net Framework Classes?

Comment: So the answer to my original question is, No, it's not possible.

Comment: @HK1: Yes, that's correct. However, the answer to the more general question of "can I use VB.NET code from Classic ASP" is "yes, just make it a COM object".

Comment: @John: Can the COM object so created be used on an ASP server without registering the COM object on the server, possibly by using [registry-free COM?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the host also support .NET you can follow those steps to achieve what you want:

1. Create new ASP.NET web application
2. Add reference to that DLL
3. Build .aspx web form that call the function in its Page_Load call it for example `Func.aspx`
4. In the classic ASP use XMLHTTP to send request to `Func.aspx` thus invoking the function and parse the results if needed.

I've done similar thing in the past to resize images on the fly from classic ASP without third party component so the concept itself is working.

Comment: Great solution. I'm using PHP in a similar manner too. Thanks for this idea.